# root locus of a system with two poles in the same place

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-theory

One of the "rules" for sketching the root locus is that for k>0 the RL exists for every part where the number of poles and zeros is odd ("to the right of it").
If we take the simple transfer function `P(S) = 1/(S^2)(S+1)`
There are even number of poles to the right of s=0 thus i thought the graph should exists there, but i see from wolfram that it does
[image]

what am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

Just read through my old notes, you are not missing anything!

As far as I've always learned the rule is:

*'The loci are on the real axis to the **left** of an odd number of poles and zeros'*

as a proof, I have looked up my Control theory book

"Feedback Control of Dynamic Systems, 7th edition" by Gene F. Franklin, J. David Powell and Abbas Emami-Naeini.

If you happen to have that book laying around somewhere, see page 263, expressed after "RULE 2."